# visualstudio.vnext (14) ctp and vs2013 side by side

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-core

Has anyone tried using VS2013 and VS14 on the same machine?

The release notes have the usual caveat so I was wondering if it was possible to still use vs2013 effectively on a machine with the vs.next ctp installed? Or if the ctp broke vs2013?

http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-14-ctp-vs

Comment: I'd wait at least until an RC before installing that on a machine that matters. VMs are your friend.

Answer (score 3):

The release notes are still accurate - don't install SxS.

I've seen cases in which SxS works and cases where the both instances of VS became unusable.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed VS 2014 CTP 4 side by side with VS 2013 Ultimate, after reading [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/84c85b/early-look-at-visual-studio-2014-ctp-2/) and haven't faced any issues yet.